# Access .aspx page from XSLT and get the HTML code

Tags: asp.net, xslt, xmlhttprequest

Am stuck at a point while accessing **.aspx page** from **XSLT**.

Using **XSLT 1.0** and **.Net 2.0**

### Problem:

I'm trying to access **.aspx** page from **XSLT**.

Here ASPX page should return as rendered HTML content.

HTML content, I have to place on the XSLT file.

**My XSLT:**

```
 <div>
    <xsl:if test="flag">
       // I need to call ASPX page and place HTML content from ASPX page
    </xsl:if>
 </div>
```

**How can I call the ASPX page and place HTML content on XSLT file?**

Please suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

After a some more turnaround work, I feel that this can be acheived only through either XHR call OR other request.

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going about this the wrong way. Instead of trying to access the page from the document, just pass the data into the document using an `XsltArgumentList`:

```
var sbXslOutput = new StringBuilder();

using (var writer = new StringWriter(sbXslOutput))
{
    //create an argument list and add some parameters
    var args = new XsltArgumentList();
    args.AddParam("arg1", String.Empty, "foo");
    args.AddParam("arg2", String.Empty, "bar");

    //execute the transformation  
    var xslTemplate = new XslCompiledTransform(false);
    xslTemplate.Load("/somefile.xsl");
    xslTemplate.Transform(Activator.CreateInstance<XmlDataDocument>(), args, writer);
}

//get the transformed text
string output = sbXslOutput.ToString();
```

Comment: thanks james for replying. Actually I have to call ASPX page from XSLT file only because currently XSLT rendering is happening at that point, based on XSLT condition I should get the HTML content from ASPX page by passing parameters to ASPX page.

Comment: there is no otherway to handle at this instance. I have to call ASPX page from XSLT only. Please suggest if any

Comment: XSLT isn't really meant for that. How can there not be another way?

Comment: Ok thanks james. I will try this somehow to fix this.. Once if I fix, I will post it. In the mean, while if you get any thoughts/suggestions let me know.

Comment: One way or another, you're going to have to pass in a parameter of some sort.

Comment: In case that by "call ASPX page" you mean sending an HTTP request to a web server (IIS), then you could try to do this using the `document()` function. However, this call will only be successful if the HTML returned is also well-formed XML.

Comment: Hello Dimitre, how you are doing today? I think it might required through HTTP request or XHR call to handle this. ASPX page will return well-formed XML, so it should not create a problem.

Comment: @SivaCharan: You'd be better of posting a new question.